# Linux command sort issues

Tags: linux, file, sorting, terminal

I am attempting to sort a .txt file that is full of data.
I attempt to sort the file by the first word of aa line in a manner that a dictionary would see it.
(I tried the sort -d)
The issue that I encounter is this-

**Input file**

---

```
100 Eminem:Detroit_Vs._Everybody.txt  
100 Fabolous:She_Wildin'.txt  
100 Fetty_Wap:Trap_Queen.txt  
100 Kanye_West:All_Day.txt  
10 ASAP_Rocky:Lord_Pretty_Flacko_Jodye_2.txt  
10 Bon_Iver:Heavenly_Father.txt  
10% Ed_Sheeran:Take_It_Back.txt  
10 Florida_Georgia_Line:Dirt.txt  
10 Jay_Electronica:Road_To_Perdition.txt
```

---

command:
*sort -d < a.txt*

**Output**

---

```
100 Eminem:Detroit_Vs._Everybody.txt  
100 Fabolous:She_Wildin'.txt  
100 Fetty_Wap:Trap_Queen.txt  
100 Kanye_West:All_Day.txt  
10 ASAP_Rocky:Lord_Pretty_Flacko_Jodye_2.txt  
10 Bon_Iver:Heavenly_Father.txt  
10% Ed_Sheeran:Take_It_Back.txt  
10 Florida_Georgia_Line:Dirt.txt  
10 Jay_Electronica:Road_To_Perdition.txt
```

---

No change occurs at all.
I'm working on a piece of code that uses this data and the way that the *10%* comes in between the *10* truly messes up the application.

I would like to see

---

```
100 Eminem:Detroit_Vs._Everybody.txt  
100 Fabolous:She_Wildin'.txt  
100 Fetty_Wap:Trap_Queen.txt  
100 Kanye_West:All_Day.txt  
10 ASAP_Rocky:Lord_Pretty_Flacko_Jodye_2.txt  
10 Bon_Iver:Heavenly_Father.txt  
10 Florida_Georgia_Line:Dirt.txt  
10 Jay_Electronica:Road_To_Perdition.txt  
10% Ed_Sheeran:Take_It_Back.txt
```

---

In other parts of the file, I have similar issues not just with numbers, but with letters and words also.
So how do I do this?

Comment: `-d` tells it to ignore characters other than alphanumerics and blanks, so it ignores the `%` character. Why should that line be put at the end?

Comment: Trying to sort `10` and `10%` is like comparing apples with pears. Perhaps the data from the first column should be of equal type in order to sort it properly.

Comment: Tobia Tesan's answer worked like a charm!
he said-
    $ sort -V takes account of the %

Comment: Yeah, this Tobia guy is pretty awesome - however, **big fat disclaimer**, if you plan to use this in production... well, consider a cleaner solution, preferably integrated in your "piece of code", whether a Perl script or a Python script or whatever it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ sort -V` takes account of the `%`

Comment: `-V` will put `10` before `100`.

Comment: It did this-
    10 Bon_Iver:Heavenly_Father.txt
    10 Florida_Georgia_Line:Dirt.txt
    10 Jay_Electronica:Road_To_Perdition.txt
    10 T.I.:Paperwork.txt
    10 Willow_Smith:Flowers.txt
    10% Ed_Sheeran:Take_It_Back.txt
Which is Exactly what i want!